# Python smtp connection is always failed in a VMware Windows machine

Tags: python, email, smtp, vmware

I m trying to use smtp class from Python 2.6.4 to send smtp email from a WinXP VMware machine.

After the send method is called, I always got this error:

socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Few stuff I noticed:

1. The same code works in the physical WinXP machine with user in/not in the domain, connected to the same smtp server.
2. If I use the smtp server which is setup in the same VM machine, then it works.

Any help is appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "...because the target machine actively refused it" usually means there's a firewall that drops any unauthorized connections. Is there a firewall service on the SMTP server that's blocking the WinXP VM's IP address?

Or, more likely: Is the SMTP server not configured to accept relays from the WinXP VM's IP address?